*ngFor and @for input decorator and casting closure
I am having different levels of closure using *ngFor directive and the new @for block.  I have a parent component that creates multiple child components using a for loop:
        <app-active-problem class="panel" *ngFor="let activeProblem of summary.activeProblems" [activeProblem] = "activeProblem" (update)="updateActiveProblem($event);"></app-active-problem>
        <!--
        @for (activeProblem of summary.activeProblems; track $index) {
            <app-active-problem class="panel" [activeProblem] = "activeProblem" (update)="updateActiveProblem($event);"></app-active-problem>
        }-->
      </ng-container>

In the child component I accept the [activeProblem] input as either a ProblemGroup | NarrativeProblem class.  In order to effectively distinguish between the two and render a view.  I create two instance variables
  problemGroup?: ProblemGroup;
  narrativeProblem?: NarrativeProblem;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.activeProblem instanceof ProblemGroup) {
      this.problemGroup = this.activeProblem as ProblemGroup;
    } else {
      this.narrativeProblem = this.activeProblem;
    }
  }

Within this same view I have a click event handler that toggles the value under the problem group (essentially mutating the object).
            <input
              clrCheckbox
              type="checkbox"
              [checked]="p.value"
              (change)="toggle($event, $index)"
            />

If I have rendered the child component using @for when assigning activeProblem to problemGroup it loses it's reference, effectively creating a copy of the object.  So any mutations I do in the child component is not reflected in the original object.
If I have rendered the child component using *ngFor directive, then it works as expected, any mutations I make to problemGroup effectively points to activeProblem.
I am hoping I can get some clarity on why this is happening?

please share the code for toggle function! please update the question and this stackblitz with the minimal code reproducible example! where the issue happens!

I think in *ngFor you didn't use the trackBy function before, right? In angular 17 when you use @for you have to set the track function which is the same as the trackBy function in the old angular version. In your code I see you set it to track $index which means angular always thinks it's still the same element and never changes. To resolve this problem, you should change the track function to something like track activeProblem.
As example:
 @for (activeProblem of summary.activeProblems; track activeProblem) {
      <app-active-problem class="panel" [activeProblem] = "activeProblem" (update)="updateActiveProblem($event);"></app-active-problem>
 }


I'd like to mark this answer as accepted.  Can you please update your answer to track activeProblem instead.  This was the issue.
